# Alpine.js: x-model – use a data attribute rather than the value of an input

Tags: alpine.js

I have a `select` field for picking a variant of a product in an e-commerce store. The values are tied to the product variant ID, and the labels are tied to the names of the variants. Each variant comes in a different pack size, which I would like to display after the input and update when the variant is changed.

This seems like a good use for the `x-model` directive in Alpine.js, but `x-model` always uses the value field of an input, which is not the field I need to display.

Is there a way to tell Alpine.js to use the field `data-packSize`, or set the `x-data` directly in each option?

```html
<form x-data="{ packSize: '{{product.variants[0].packSize}}' }"">

  <select x-model="packSize">
    <option value="variant1" data-packSize="30"> variant 1 title </option>
    <option value="variant2" data-packSize="20"> variant 2 title </option>
  </select>

  Pack of <span x-text="packSize"></span> items

</form>
```

Here I would like the span to update between `30` and `20`, instead it updates between `variant1` and `variant2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the backend you can also generate an auxiliary object called `packSizes` that you can use to display the selected variant's packsize. You can put an [`x-init` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/init#standalone-x-init) on each select option where you add the respective label to the `packSizes` object.

```html
 <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
 
 <form x-data="{ packSize: 'variant1', packSizes: {} }"">

  <select x-model="packSize">
    <option value="variant1" x-init="packSizes['variant1'] = 30"> variant 1 title </option>
    <option value="variant2" x-init="packSizes['variant2'] = 20"> variant 2 title </option>
    <option value="variant3" x-init="packSizes['variant3'] = 10"> variant 3 title </option>
  </select>

  Pack of <span x-text="packSizes[packSize]"></span> items

</form>
```